# nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/StandardServletAsyncWebRequest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a standard spring app (i.e. not a spring boot app) and the version of spring is 4.2.13.RELEASE.

I'm trying to use StreamingResponseBody which I have done many times, but on this occasion I am getting this error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/request/async/StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with spring boot, you must include this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is the spring boot parent that I'm using in my project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

For non spring boot applications you can use the next dependency in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This config may solve your exception.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not using spring boot, and the spring-web jar is in my project and if I inspect the jar I can see the correct class in the jar. Weird.

Comment: Can you post the dependencies section of your pom?